# MongoDB - eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mongodb

I need to create a server-side app that saving information to a mongoDB ,
I'm working with java-eclipse-IDE and i have some problems with that .

First ,
I download the mongo-2.7.2.jar and add it to the path ( project ->properties-> java build path -> add jar -> (adding the mongo-2.7.2.jar file ) .

When I press "Run" without writing any other line except the empty - class & main function 
The console writing me that :

CLI (1) [java application] path date

---

Usage : [--bucket bucketname] action
  where  action is one of:
      list                      : lists all files in the store
      put filename              : puts the file filename into the store
      get filename1 filename2   : gets filename1 from store and sends to filename2
      md5 filename              : does an md5 hash on a file in the db (for testing)

I tried to put a system.out.print("indications") in the main function but the console showing me the same output ...

onother interesting fact is when i'm wrting a code using  a mongo DB the compiler accepted the code and not throwing errors ( seems he accepted the mongo-2.7.2.jar ).

second ,
I thoght maby i need to install a mongoDB plugin to eclipse , should i?
third ,
I saw that maven is integrated a mongoDB service , is it right that i should download maven to eclipse for handle mongoDB?

I need help soon as possible ....
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like its trying to do something with GridFS but is missing a bucket name... are you using GridFS?

Comment: I dont know about gridFS that's mean i dont use it? the only thing i can guess is maybe he is trying to create a DB that already exist ?

Comment: I'm not sure, we need more information to be able to help you. Is this a brand new install of eclipse? Did you follow the instructions for adding jars to a project / build path in eclipse? Did you read this: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java) ?