# MongoDB Java driver error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have put together a simple program that connects to a running MongoDB instance, gets the existing db and collection (previously created) and inserts a document. It looks like this:

```
    public class MyClass {

        public void main(String args[]) {

        try {
             MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
             String connectionPoint = client.getConnectPoint();

             DB db = (DB) client.getDatabase("aDb");
             DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("aCollection");

             BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
             document.put("name", "james");
             collection.insert(document);
             client.close();

            } catch (MongoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am, however, returned with the following message when I run this as a Java Application in Eclipse:

```
Usage : [--bucket bucketname] action
  where  action is one of:
      list                      : lists all files in the store
      put filename              : puts the file filename into the store
      get filename1 filename2   : gets filename1 from store and sends to filename2
      md5 filename              : does an md5 hash on a file in the db (for testing)
```

I am not really sure what this means and I have been struggling to find any real solution on line ([MongoDB - eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434407/mongodb-eclipse)). My Referenced Libraries include both mongo-java-driver-3.2.1.jar (where com.mongodb.client.gridfs is part of it) and bson-3.2.1.jar and my MongoDB instance is correctly running. Am I missing anything really obvious?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

I.

EDIT

pom.xml file for the small application:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MongoConnection</groupId>
  <artifactId>MongoConnection</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You only get this error if you would be using GridFS. GridFS will raise this error if the bucket name is missing. Are you referencing GridFS somewhere in your code base ?

Comment: I have had a look at my 'Run Configurations' and that for running this Java application strangely points to CLI -com.mongodb.gridfs and it seems to be the only matching item for the project. I am not sure where I went wrong...

Comment: Are you using Gradle or Maven ?

Comment: Hi, I have a pom.file with the main dependencies, but I was actually simply running it as a Java application: right click on the project -> Run As -> Java Application. I can successfully run mvn -package from the command line on the project, but I do not seem to see any newly created document (I must say that I am a beginner in Maven)

Comment: @Jaco, thanks for your help so far. I have just added the pom.xml in case this can be of any use to clarify my issue. Thank you